# write into a file using variables without duplicating

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Trying to write a function in shell which takes three arguments `a_text_to_be_matched`, `new_text` and `file_name`. If the text_to_be_matched is found then the complete line is replaced by the `new_text` else it simply echoes the `new_text` in file.
Following is the code I have tried but it breaks when the $to_write has spaces in between.

```
function write_once(){
to_grep="$1";
to_write="$2";
file="$3";
grep $to_grep $file;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    sed -i '/'"$to_grep"'/c\'$"to_write" $file;
else
    echo "$to_write" >> "$file";
fi
}
```

Comment: an example would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sed -i "s/(.*)?(${text_to_be_matched})?(.*)?/${new_text}" $file
```

Comment: Does it work inside a function with text to be matched passed as a variable? I tried on bash, wasn't working!

Comment: BTW, why you need `(.*)?` in the match?